# Call a theorem using let-in

Tags: coq

I have a function `f` returning a pair. Then I prove some results about it.
In my lemmas, my first attempt to get each component was using `let (x, y) := f z in`. But then, trying to use these lemmas seems cumbersome. `apply` does not work directly, I have to add the lemma in the hypothesis using `pose proof` or a variant of it and destruct `f z` to be able to use it. Is there a way to use let-in smoothly in lemmas ? Or is it discouraged because it is painful to use ?

To complete my question, here are the other attempts I made to write lemmas about `f`. I tried using `fst (f z)` and `snd (f z)` directly, but I also found it cumbersome. Finally, I started my lemmas with `forall x y, (x,y) = f z ->`.

Here is a concrete example.

```
Require Import List. Import ListNotations.

Fixpoint split {A} (l:list A) :=
  match l with
  | [] => ([], [])
  | [a] => ([a], [])
  | a::b::l => let (l1, l2) := split l in (a::l1, b::l2)
  end.

Lemma split_in : forall {A} (l:list A) x,
  let (l1, l2) := split l in 
  In x l1 \/ In x l2 <-> In x l.

Lemma split_in2 : forall {A} (l:list A) x,
  In x (fst (split l)) \/ In x (snd (split l)) <-> In x l.

Lemma split_in3 : forall {A} (l:list A) x l1 l2,
  (l1, l2) = split l ->
  In x l1 \/ In x l2 <-> In x l.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have found what I believe is the correct solution.  `let (l1, l2) := ... in ...` will block reduction and break everything.  Whether you use `split_in2` or `split_in3` depends on what your starting point is.

Note, however, that turning on `Primitive Projections` and redefining `prod` as a primitive record will make it so that `split_in` and `split_in2` are actually the same theorem, because `split l` and `(fst (split l), snd (split l))` are judgmentally equal.  You can do this with

```
Set Primitive Projections.
Record prod {A B} := pair { fst : A ; snd : B }.
Arguments prod : clear implicits.
Arguments pair {A B}.
Add Printing Let prod.
Notation "x * y" := (prod x y) : type_scope.
Notation "( x , y , .. , z )" := (pair .. (pair x y) .. z) : core_scope.
Hint Resolve pair : core.
```

Comment: I believe we also need `Arguments pair {A B}.` to make it more like the standard `prod` type.

Comment: No, I add curly braces around `{A B}` in the definition of `prod` (which automatically adds them for `pair`, `fst`, and `snd`), and hen remove them from `prod`.

Comment: It didn't work for me (Coq 8.7.1): `Check (0,0) : nat * nat`, because `pair` has those type arguments explicit

Comment: Does this mean that if `Primitive Projections` were activated, `split_in` would be usable ? Do you know if this will be activated by default in a near future or what prevents from doing so ?

Comment: @AntonTrunov huh, I never realized that the curly braces only applied to the type former and the projections, not to the constructor.  Thanks!

Comment: @eponier Indeed, if you copy-paste the code redefining `prod` as a primitive record above your code, then you can prove `split_in2` by `intros; apply split_in`.

Comment: @eponier Regarding turning them on by default, I just made https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/6609

Comment: @JasonGross Thanks.