# Defining equality relation for infinite trees

Tags: coq, coinduction

In coq i can define equality relations for coinductive types whose components are pairs:

```
Section Pairs.
Variable (A:Type).
CoInductive Stream :=
  cons : (A * Stream) -> Stream.

CoInductive Stream_eq : Stream -> Stream -> Prop := 
  stream_eq : forall t1 t2 b1 b2, Stream_eq (t1) (t2)
               -> (b1 = b2)
               -> Stream_eq (cons (b1,t1)) (cons (b2,t2)).
End Pairs.
```

I can also do this for types whose components are functions:

```
Section Functions.
Variable (A:Type).
CoInductive Useless :=
   cons_useless : (A -> Useless) -> Useless.

CoInductive Useless_eq : Useless -> Useless -> Prop := 
  useless_eq : forall t1 t2, (forall b, Useless_eq (t1 b) (t2 b))
                   -> Useless_eq (cons_useless t1) (cons_useless t2).
End Functions.
```

But i can't seem to define analogous relation for types whose components are functions to pairs:

```
Section FunctionsToPairs.
Variable (A:Type).
Variable (B:Type).
CoInductive InfiniteTree :=
  cons_tree : (A -> B * InfiniteTree) -> InfiniteTree.
CoInductive Tree_eq : InfiniteTree -> InfiniteTree -> Prop := 
  tree_eq : forall (t1:A -> B*InfiniteTree) (t2:A -> B*InfiniteTree), 
     (forall b, let (a1, c1) := (t1 b) in
                let (a2, c2) := (t2 b) in Tree_eq c1 c2 /\ a1 = a2)
                   -> Tree_eq (cons_tree t1) (cons_tree t2).
End FunctionsToPairs.
```

I get error:

```
Non strictly positive occurrence of "Tree_eq" in
 "forall t1 t2 : A -> B * InfiniteTree,
  (forall b : A, let (a1, c1) := t1 b in let (a2, c2) := t2 b in Tree_eq c1 c2 /\ a1 = a2) ->
  Tree_eq (cons_tree t1) (cons_tree t2)".
```

Is there any way to have a well-defined equality relation for the InfiniteTree type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition is mostly rejected due to the use of let-in constructs that prevents the checker from establishing that the occurrence of `Tree_eq c1 c2` in the constructor `tree_eq` is valid. If you remove them, or write them differently, the definition is accepted by Coq.

For example, the following works:

```
CoInductive Tree_eq : InfiniteTree -> InfiniteTree -> Prop := 
  tree_eq : forall (t1:A -> B*InfiniteTree) (t2:A -> B*InfiniteTree), 
     (forall b, let x1 := (t1 b) in
                let x2 := (t2 b) in Tree_eq (snd x1) (snd x2) /\ fst x1 = fst x2)
                   -> Tree_eq (cons_tree t1) (cons_tree t2).
```

Note that with primitive projections enabled, your original definition works (the idea comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48279204/call-a-theorem-using-let-in#48296323) by @JasonGross).

```
Set Primitive Projections.

Record prod {A B} := pair { fst : A ; snd : B }.
Arguments prod : clear implicits.
Arguments pair {A B}.
Add Printing Let prod.
Notation "x * y" := (prod x y) : type_scope.
Notation "( x , y , .. , z )" := (pair .. (pair x y) .. z) : core_scope.
Hint Resolve pair : core.

Section FunctionsToPairs.
Variable (A:Type).
Variable (B:Type).
CoInductive InfiniteTree :=
  cons_tree : (A -> B * InfiniteTree) -> InfiniteTree.
CoInductive Tree_eq : InfiniteTree -> InfiniteTree -> Prop := 
  tree_eq : forall (t1:A -> B*InfiniteTree) (t2:A -> B*InfiniteTree), 
     (forall b, let (a1, c1) := (t1 b) in
                let (a2, c2) := (t2 b) in Tree_eq c1 c2 /\ a1 = a2)
                   -> Tree_eq (cons_tree t1) (cons_tree t2).
End FunctionsToPairs.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think i may have figured out how to do this without modifying InfiniteTree type using mutual coinduction.

```
CoInductive Tree_eq : InfiniteTree -> InfiniteTree -> Prop := 
  tree_eq : forall (t1:A -> B*InfiniteTree) (t2:A -> B*InfiniteTree), 
                    (forall b,  Pair_eq (t1 b) (t1 b))
                   -> Tree_eq (cons_tree t1) (cons_tree t2)
  with Pair_eq : B*InfiniteTree -> B*InfiniteTree -> Prop :=
    pair_eq : forall b1 b2 t1 t2, b1 = b2 -> Tree_eq t1 t2 -> Pair_eq (b1, t1) (b2, t2).
```

One downside is that this way it's probably harder to construct proofs of Tree_eq than using method described in Arthur's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53009934/7264503).

Answer (score 0):

Coq gets confused when there is a recursive occurrence of a type under a destructor.  You can fix this issue by slightly changing the definition of the tree type:

```
Section FunctionsToPairs.
Variable (A:Type).
Variable (B:Type).
CoInductive InfiniteTree :=
  cons_tree : (A -> B) -> (A -> InfiniteTree) -> InfiniteTree.
CoInductive Tree_eq : InfiniteTree -> InfiniteTree -> Prop :=
  tree_eq : forall (f1 f2 : A -> B) (t1 t2 : A -> InfiniteTree),
    (forall x, f1 x = f2 x) ->
    (forall x, Tree_eq (t1 x) (t2 x)) ->
    Tree_eq (cons_tree f1 t1) (cons_tree f2 t2).
End FunctionsToPairs.
```

Comment: This is suboptimal as i plan to extract Haskell program from this and while a->(b,c) and (a->b, a->c) may be (nearly) isomorphic, they behave differently in terms of performance - in the first case the function gets called only once